# Is there an American English equivalent for the British "moggie" for a non-purebred cat?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english, british-english, dialectal-equivalent

I'm an American (and fond of cats). I'm familiar with the British term "moggie" for a non-purebred cat--basically the equivalent of "mutt" for a dog. I've never heard any American English equivalent of "moggie." Is there one?

(If there isn't, I'll use "moggie," because we have a need for it.)

Comment: They cover it pretty well right here: http://cats.about.com/od/coatcolorpatternstypes/f/domesticcat.htm , even to the extent of including "moggie".

Comment: ODO says that a moggie is 'a cat, **typically** one that is does not have a pedigree or is otherwise unremarkable.'. It's often merely a term of endearment.

Comment: Actually, in the US "mongrel" has more the meaning of a mixed-breed dog, while "mutt" is simply an unimpressive dog.

Comment: 'Moggie' is used with these meanings: 1. (orig.) a girl, a young woman. Later: an untidily dressed woman. 2. A stuffed figure; a guy, scarecrow, etc. 3. A calf, a cow. 4. A (domestic) cat, esp. a non-pedigree or otherwise unremarkable one.

Comment: Our vet (northern VA) puts down DSH (Domestic Short Haired) under "Breed" for a non-pedigreed short haired cat.  I don't know what they put down for a non-pedigreed long-haired, but probably DLH.   If you need this term, is it because you have adopted a rescue cat?

Comment: @ab2 I can confirm your hunch. DLH is used on vet forms in the US, for my fuzzy buddy at least. :)

Comment: @JEL I have only ever heard of "moggie" or [**moggy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moggy) in connection with cats, I'd like to see which dictionary places *a girl/young woman* as its principal meaning, followed by a scarecrow/mannequin, a calf and *then* a cat.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, "1. a. colloq. (orig. and chiefly Sc. and Eng. regional). Originally: a girl, a young woman. Later: an untidily dressed woman. Now rare." ["moggie, n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120721 (accessed November 17, 2015).] Same source for the others.

Comment: @JEL how about an *updated* online dictionary reference. I don't have access to the OED

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you have a problem with Sept. 2015?

Comment: @JEL  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moggy, https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/moggy, http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moggy and Oxford Online Dictionaries http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moggie Those links is also called *evidence*

Comment: @Mari-LouA, dueling dictionaries now? Why do you think your experience trumps the evidence? Are you contradicting me or the OED?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The first meaning listed in many dictionaries isn't the "principal" meaning, it's the oldest.

Comment: @Nathaniel Fine, I get that it's an obsolete term, but listing "cat" as meaning (4) is extremely misleading. Did you see the five dictionary links I posted? I didn't see any mentioning about a stuffed figure, like "Guy Fawkes", and that is supposedly second. The OED is a GREAT dictionary, but years pass by before terms are updated to the present day.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think there's any doubt that the principal meaning of *moggy* these days is *cat*, and I bet the editors of the OED would agree.  But their claim to fame is including every significant way the word has ever been used, and they put them in order of oldest to newest, not considering popularity.  My older print copy cites 1825 for the first use of "pet name for cow," 1886 for "untidily dressed woman," and 1911 for "cat," in that order, but gives many more examples for the last usage.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like **domestic short-haired cat** and **domestic long-haired cat** are standard in American English.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_short-haired_cat):

> A **domestic short-haired cat** is a cat of mixed ancestry – thus not belonging to any particular recognized cat breed – possessing a coat of short fur. In British English, they are often referred to as **moggies**.

If you want simple, ***house cat*** and ***alley cat*** often connote mixed breed, especially the latter, but are technically terms describing where the cat lives, not its ancestry.  Nonetheless, *house cat* is used by some cat organizations ([source](http://www.webcitation.org/6ErvWYADX)) to refer to mixed-breed cats of both long-hair and short-hair varities.

Answer (score 5):

I'll go with ***mongrel cat***.

> alley cat: a homeless, mongrel cat [Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/alley-cat)
>
> *Thomas, a 10-year-old moggie (a British nickname for a housecat or mongrel cat), claims to be Britain's fattest cat at 28 pounds*. [Books Google](https://books.google.fr/books?id=shAHJQwXslYC&pg=PA121&dq=%22mongrel+cat%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAWoVChMIwfWhirqXyQIVRtkaCh3JzwPc#v=onepage&q=%22mongrel%20cat%22&f=false)

Comment: When Bob Kanefsky (US) wrote a [filk](http://mindstalk.net/filk/lyrics/NoMogLand.html) (parody) of Eric Bogle's (UK/Aus) [Nobody's moggy](http://www.traditionalmusic.co.uk/song-midis/Nobodys_Moggy_Now.htm), he evidently used "Moggy" as the cat's name. I often wondered whether this was just the exigencies of rhyme and meter, or whether he didn't recognise the word and assumed it was a name.

Answer (score 5):

I hadn't realized it, but a smorgasbord of choices exists, with one or another better or worse, depending on your specific reference cat-sense. The following are some, omitting 'moggie' and others already mentioned in earlier answers. If the sense desired includes a denoted (rather than connoted) 'mixed breed', 'housecat' (already detailed in another answer) in use is probably closest to the use of the British 'moggie' (other than 'mog', also British).

Obsolete, archaic or rare:

- bad (obs.)
- gib, or gib-cat (obs. gib, arch. and dial. gib-cat)
- mewer (rare)
- mewler (obs., rare)
- Tibert (arch.)
- miauler (rare)

Others:

- baudrons (Sc.)
- puss-cat (Am. or Brit., nursery or colloq.)
- puss (colloq.)
- grimalkin (esp. an old she-cat)
- miaower
- pussycat (colloq., orig. nursery)
- pussy (nursery and colloq.)
- tigerkin
- pussums (colloq.)
- mog (Brit. colloq.)

(All terms and designations [obsolete, archaic, rare, etc.] from the [OED Historical Thesaurus](http://www.oed.com/view/th/class/40833).)

The 'tigerkin' choice seems best to me, and avoids denigrating the cat while at the same time suggesting in a positive way that the cat is a mixture of breeds.

Comment: ["A grimalkin (also called a greymalkin) is an archaic term for a cat."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimalkin). Or if you prefer books: [Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grimalkin&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrimalkin%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Well, Wikipedia cites the OED as its source for grimalkin being archaic, and most people agree NGrams is a reputable resource for facts and figures.